# multirowcell in the final column of a table has vertical line partly missing

Tags: tables, multirow, makecell

I am using the `makecell` and `multirow` packages.

The only problem I can't solve is having a `\multirowcell` in the final column of the table leads to the right most vertical line only going part way down.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}%gives tables more vertical stretch
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|cc|cc|c|}
        \hline
        \multirowcell{2.5}{\textbf{Knockout}} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{H1}} &  
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{C1}} &
        \multirowcell{2.5}{\textbf{Efficiency}}\\ \cline{2-5}
        &
        \thead{Total \\ number \\ picked} & \thead{Number \\ successfully \\ targeted} & \thead{Total \\ number \\ picked} & \thead{Number \\ successfully \\ targeted}\\ 
        \hline
        \thead{Original \\ KO \\ (1Sg)} & 25 & 1 & 20 & 2 & 4-10\%\\
        \hline
        \thead{2Sg KO1} & 11 & 10 & 15 & 15 & 90-100\%\\
        \hline
        \thead{2Sg KO4-7} & 11 & 2 & 14 & 1 & 7-18\%\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{\textbf{CRISPR/Cas9 knockout efficiency }}
\label{table:efficiency}
}
\end{table}
```

and here is what the output is:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an empty cell at the end of the line, so LaTeX can put the vertical rule at the end of it:

```
\thead{Total \\ number \\ picked} & 
\thead{Number \\ successfully \\ targeted} & 
\thead{Total \\ number \\ picked} & 
\thead{Number \\ successfully \\ targeted} & \\
```

Note the added `&` at the end of the line